# Why is LocalSymbol treated differently inside a Module scope?

Tags: persistence, localsymbol

Wanting to persist credentials entered via a dialog. While doing so I wanted to scope them by prepending a type to the symbol name. Came across this behavior which I find odd:

```
DeleteObject[LocalObjects[]]
```

```
f[key_] := Module[{},
  If[ValueQ[LocalSymbol[key]],
   Print["I have a value for " <> key],
   Print["No value for " <> key]
   ]
  ]
```

`f[b]` returns: `No value for b`

The trouble starts if I use a locally defined variable:

```
g[k_] := Module[{key = k},
  If[ValueQ[LocalSymbol[key]],
   Print["I have a value for " <> key],
   Print["No value for " <> key]
   ];
  ]
```

`g["c"]` returns: `I have a value for c`

`key` is still a string in the second definition - any idea why `ValueQ[]` thinks it is set?

I can probably manage scoping with a separate directory for each type, but why!?

Answer (score 4):

A simpler version:

```
key = "c";
ValueQ @ LocalSymbol[key]
```

> True

What's happening is that [`ValueQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ValueQ) has the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll):

```
Attributes[ValueQ]
```

> {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}

So, [`ValueQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ValueQ) is testing whether the unevaluated `LocalSymbol[key]` has a value, and of course it does. The value is `LocalSymbol["c"]`. It's basically the same thing as asking:

```
ValueQ[key]
```

> True

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the problem will not occur if you use `With` instead of `Module` in the definition of `g[k_]`.

Comment: Thank you both. I guess a saner way to see if my LocalSymbol has been set may be to evaluate it and see what it's `Head` is.